# Order for building dependencies by mvn

Tags: java, maven

Greeting, guys.
Could you please help me solve the issue:
In my pom.xml (for example application calls 'maven-Hell') i have 2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dor.lub</groupId>
    <artifactId>aaa</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dor.dabu</groupId>
    <artifactId>ddd</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

When i run **mvn clean install** for 'maven-Hell' application I want to build (clean install, as well) for two dependencies (see above) before 'maven-Hell' app.
P.S. They are also my modules, not like parent and child.
Any idea how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: If they're your own created dependencies, you'll either need to `mvn deploy` their artifacts to some repository, or `mvn install` them to your local repo. Otherwise, the depending project won't see them unless they're maven modules of it (basically, subprojects).

Comment: They are already in local .m2. The main idea, when versions of dependencies increase, i need to first build that dependencies. And only after that run mvn clean install on main project. But i want to run jenkins build, for example, (which starts mvn clean install) for main project - and inside of that the mvn saw requires for building dependencies first.

Comment: Note that whatever build agent jenkins is using will have its own local .m2 repo. Unless it built those dependencies first automatically, it won't see them. It sounds like you're at the point of needing a (non-local) maven repo that you can deploy built artifacts to, so it can simply grab the latest/needed version of your dependencies.

Comment: I know, Jenkins has personal maven and .m2. It was just example. I can build app localy too. So, anyway, i have solution by running custom mvn command, but it's uncomfortable and want be obviously for other devs.
I'm wondering: how to solve it by running only mvn clean install for 'maven-Hell' app? By spring-maven-plugin or dependencyManager?

Comment: if you have a setup with Jenkins etc. you have to deploy those artifacts into your own repository manager to make it possible to be consumed by others... That means the other project must correctly deploy into the repository manager  (creating a release) afterwards you can consume them in other projects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mvn clean install -pl MICRO-SERVICE-NAME -P mvnProfile -am -f pom.xml

Mvn will run clean install on owns modules from project